# Combining 2 apps in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, routes

I'm trying to learn React for 2 weeks now and I already made some great progress. I made 2 applications that are visual and functional done.

Now I was wondering if it is possible to combine this 2 App's in 1 bigger application, so I can redirect from a login to the other applications Index. I tried to find some information on the internet but nothing was really clear for me...

So I basically made a Login / signup app with an empty homepage.
And I made a second kinda forum app which I want to implement in the empty homepage of the login app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ReactDOM twice.

after successfully login you must have to serve dashboard page from server then on document ready you have to bind second app using ReactDom on div in blank dashboard.